# Get all files except minified files in gulp.src

Tags: gulp, glob, minimatch

I try to select all files EXCEPT minified files.

I have this file structure :

```
lib/
    angular/
        angular.js
        angular.min.js
    lodash/
        lodash.js
        lodash.min.js
```

I try this :

```
var pattern = ["./lib/**/*!(.min).*"];
gulp.src(pattern).pipe(using({}));
```

But this doesn't works : i get all files, even if they are minified.

(With gulp-using i get :

```
[gulp] Using file ./lib/angular/angular.js
[gulp] Using file ./lib/angular/angular.min.js
[gulp] Using file ./lib/lodash/lodash.js
[gulp] Using file ./lib/lodash/lodash.min.js
```

)

Any idea ?

Thanks you in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question has been asked 3 years ago,
but I will post this answer, so it might help someone else.

```
var pattern = ["./lib/**/!(*.min)*.js"];
```

and if you need to add multiple excludes, so, for example, you want to exclude `fileName.js`,  `*.spec` and also all `*.min` files you can use `|`

```
var pattern = ["./lib/**/!(fileName|*.spec|*.min)*.js"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Change pattern to

```
var pattern = ["./lib/**/*", "!./lib/**/*.min.*"];
```

This reads as "get all files anywhere under lib, then exclude files under lib that have '.min.' in their name"

Comment: Yes this works. 

But in fact, i need to negate this pattern for a more complex expression. So i need to write it in one string